# How to save a record in a controller to two different tables in go

Tags: mysql, sql, go

People, I am trying to save an employee in the employee table, it already saves and everything is fine, the problem is when I try to save the schedule that is related to another table where schedule_id is the foreign of the employee table and is related to the id of the time table, this is the code:

Controlador

```
func Save(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    employe := models.Employe{}

    db := common.GetConnection()

    error := json.NewDecoder(request.Body).Decode(&employe)

    if error != nil {
        log.Fatal(error)
        common.SendError(writer, http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    randomBytes := make([]byte, 2)
    _, err := rand.Read(randomBytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(error)
        common.SendError(writer, http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    employe.PinEmploye = hex.EncodeToString(randomBytes)

    horary := models.Employe{Arrival: employe.Arrival, Departure: employe.Departure}
    error = db.Save(&horary).Error

    if error != nil {
        log.Fatal(error)
        common.SendError(writer, http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    employe.ScheduleId = horary.ID

    error = db.Save(&employe).Error

    if error != nil {
        log.Fatal(error)
        common.SendError(writer, http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    json, _ := json.Marshal(employe)
    common.SendResponse(writer, http.StatusCreated, json)
    fmt.Println(employe)
}
```

structs

```
type Employe struct {
    ID         int    `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment"`
    PinEmploye string `json:"pinEmploye" gorm:"FOREIGNKEY:PinEmploye" `
    FirstName  string `json:"first_name" `
    LastName   string `json:"last_name"`
    Company    string `json:"company"`
    Position   string `json:"position"`
    ScheduleId int    `json:"schedule_id"`
    // Arrival    time.Time `json:"arrival"`
    // Departure  time.Time `json:"departure"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"fechacreacion"`
}
```

Horary:

```
type Horary struct {
    ID        int       `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment"`
    Arrival   time.Time `json:"arrival"`
    Departure time.Time `json:"departure"`
}
```

I tried to do it with entities but I still don't know very well about the subject

```
type Employe struct {
    ID         int       `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;auto_increment"`
    PinEmploye string    `json:"pinEmploye" gorm:"FOREIGNKEY:PinEmploye" `
    FirstName  string    `json:"first_name" `
    LastName   string    `json:"last_name"`
    Company    string    `json:"company"`
    Position   string    `json:"position"`
    ScheduleId int       `json:"schedule_id"`
    CreatedAt  time.Time `json:"fechacreacion"`
}
```

I have tried with entity model but still can't do it, I tried to do it with chatGPT but still can't

Comment: "can't do it" meaning what? What problem are you having?

Comment: At the moment of bringing it in the front there are 00:00:00